Common N-channel mosfet for multiple voltages
I have a circuit that may be simplified to this:

The motor icons are actually some devices that require different input voltage (to be specific - OLED display with 12V source, addressable LEDs with 5V source, etc...). All these devices used to have common ground. After measuring idle current it looks like some of them can't go sleep, so I want to introduce this mosfet to brake the circuit, controlling it by 3.3V GPIO.
I'd like to know if this schematic will work?

What else is connected to the loads? || There is no such thing as an "NPN" MOSFET; perhaps you meant N-channel?

Yes, N-channel. The loads are OLED display and LEDs, in terms of current - up to 200mA. The logic circuits of the display and LEDs are wired and working, but not included in this schematic

Wired to what? -- When you disconnect ground, what input voltage will these devices see? If they're connected to MCU outputs for example, some of which are high and some of which are low, what happens?

Yeah, based on the answers provided, I realize that disconnecting ground will not work at all. so, I'd need to break power wires...

No. Connecting the three loads together like this will drive current backwards through the lower-voltage ones.
You might be able to make this work by adding one diode per load, but it'd be better to just put three MOSFETs with their gates tied together.

Thanks for the answer, makes sense...

Not only should you use separate MOSFETs but probably you should use high-side switches for some or all of those devices. It's not necessary for something like a non-addressable LED or a motor, but for addressable LEDs, displays, etc. that have inputs and outputs it's a very good idea.
And you should also make sure that things like inputs to the OLED display are driven low before you cut the power so that current cannot flow into the protection networks unless you are very sure that is okay.
It's also not a bad idea to add some series resistors to limit the current in case a transient condition occurs that leads to the device being powered through inputs momentarily.

Thanks, good to know these nuances. So, I'd like first to concentrate only on the LEDs power since eacn one of them (SK9822) draws 1ma in idle state, and the OLED may be put into sleep mode programmatically. Is a dedicated high-side switch the best option for this case?

High side switch and drive SDI low, with a resistor of at least a few hundred ohms in series.
